# how can get image from a relative path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

i am working in asp .net mvc3.

i want to get a image which exist in this location in my project
G:\projects\CalcoWoms\CalcoWOMS\Content\pictures\calcologo.png

CalcoWOMS is my project name. i want to fetch this calcologo.png in following line please check following line and tell me how should write this following line in correct way.?

iTextSharp.text.Image gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("~/calcologo.png");

means in place of ("~/calcologo.png"); what path i should write ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `MapPath`

```
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/pictures/calcologo.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `"%~dp0calcologo.png"`.
`%~dp0` means current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HostingEnvironment object along with Path.Combine

```
Path.Combine(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "calcologo.png");
```

Of course, @HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath will only take you to the root of your application, so you might need to use "Content/picturescalcologo.png".